Prove or disprove an elementary inequality: $\sin\frac1n>\sin\frac1{2n+1}+\sin\frac1{2n+2},\quad \forall n=1,2,3,\cdots.$
It is easy to prove that
$$\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}<\frac1{n},\quad \forall n=1,2,3,\cdots.$$
Inspired by this inequality, I want to know the following inequalities:
$$\sin\frac{1}{n+1}<\sin\frac{1}{2n+1}+\sin\frac{1}{2n+2}<\sin\frac1{n},\quad \forall n=1,2,3,\cdots.$$
What I have done now is：
$$\sin\frac{1}{2n+1}+\sin\frac{1}{2n+2}-\sin\frac{1}{n+1}
=\sin\frac{1}{2n+1}+\sin\frac{1}{2n+2}-2\sin\frac{1}{2n+2}\cos\frac1{2n+2}$$
$$=\sin\frac{1}{2n+1}-\sin\frac{1}{2n+2}\left(2\cos\frac1{2n+2}-1\right)
>\sin\frac{1}{2n+1}-\sin\frac{1}{2n+2}>0.$$
i.e. the LHS is ture. But the same proof technique doesn't apply to the RHS. But the Wolfram mathemtica gives that it seems right for $1\leq n\leq50$,

Any help and hints will welcome!

for real $0 < x < 1$  we know $ x - \frac{x^3}{6}  < \sin x <  x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} $  which should work easily for large $n.$  Note $\sin x < x$  also

Use the following lower and upper bound on $\sin(x)$ for $0<x<1$:
$$
x \geq \sin(x) \geq x - \frac{x^2}{6}.
$$
For instance for the first inequality you should check:
$$
\frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{2n+1}  - \frac{1}{6(2n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{6(2n+2)^2}.
$$

should be $x^3 / 6$ not $x^2/6$

Note that for $x<1$ we have that $x^2/6 \geq x^3/6$. This make the algebra a little bit easier without sacrificing the inequality.

Maybe some comment in the answer for why you can use $x^2$ in the formula rather than the expected $x^3.$ A comment is not enough.

The first inequality does not require the MacLaurin expansion. It can be proved similarly as in OP
$$\sin{1\over 2n+1}+\sin{1\over 2n+2}>2\sin{1\over 2n+2}\\
> 2\sin{1\over 2n+2}\cos{1\over 2n+2}=\sin{1\over n+1}$$

Thank you for your answer. Actually your second $\geq$ can be $>$.

One thing you could have done, at least for large $n$, is to use Taylor series
$$\sin \left(\frac{1}{2 n+1}\right)+\sin
   \left(\frac{1}{2 n+2}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{1}{ n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{4n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\sin \left(\frac{1}{2 n+1}\right)+\sin
   \left(\frac{1}{2 n+2}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{1}{ n}\right)=-\frac{3}{4n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
